# I'm getting compilation error even though everything seems to be right

Tags: c

I was trying to make a simple C program which, given X and Y coordinates, tells the quadrant. 
I'm getting an error:

```
cordinate.c: In function ‘main’:
cordinate.c:28:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

As far as I know syntax-wise i's correct.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int x, y;

    printf("enter the cordinate x and y\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    if ((x > 0) && (y > 0)) {
        printf("The point lies in 1st quadrant \n");
    } else if ((x < 0) && (y > 0)) {
        printf("The point lies in 2nd quadrant \n");
    } else if ((x < 0) && (y < 0)) {    
        printf("The point lies in 3rd quadrant \n");
    } else ( (x>0) && (y<0) )

    {   
        printf("The point lies in 4th quadrant \n");
    }
}
```

And when I do whatever is said I get the output as

```
input 
22
33
output
The point lies in 1st quadrant 
The point lies in 4th quadrant
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: you cannot write a condition after `else`

Comment: Why do people show error messages including line numbers and do not refer to these numbers in the code they show?

Comment: Thanks Nasr I got the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 else ( (x>0) && (y<0) )
 {   
       printf("The point lies in 4th quadrant \n");
  }
```

else doesnt take any condition. Use

```
 else if ( (x>0) && (y<0) )
```

or only `else` .

Comment: Thanks a lot I got the output.

Answer (score 2):

After `else` there is no conditions, fix your program like this:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  void main()
 {
    int x,y;

    printf("enter the cordinate x and y\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    if((x>0) && (y>0))
    {
        printf("The point lies in 1st quadrant \n");
    }  
    .
    .
    .

    else   // The condition removed form here
    {   
        printf("The point lies in 4th quadrant \n");
    }
}
```

`else` means that if all conditions fails then it will execute what is after `else` so there no need to specify condition after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help I got the output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing an `if` keyword on this line:

```
} else ( (x>0) && (y<0) )
```

Also, you shouldn't use `void main()`. [You can only use either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/3601420)

Comment: Thanks I m a beginner in c and I didn't knew about this thanks a lot for ur help